# Is this a valid Hex value?

Tags: java, hex

I'm reading a series of Hex values, reading the value `0x03B6 using the code :

```
Integer.parseInt("0x03B6",16);
```

results in exception :

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "0x03B6"
```

If however I remove the 0x at beginning of value the result is converted to HEX correctly :

```
Integer.parseInt("03B6",16)
```

Is `0X` a convention to indicate it's a hex value ? `03B6` is valid Hex ?

Using a Hex calculator - https://www.calculator.net/hex-calculator.html also does not recognize `0x03B6`  but does recognize `03B6`

Comment: `0x` is the prefix for a *hexadecimal literal.*  See [here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

Comment: Note that `"0x03B6"` is not a hexadecimal literal; it's a String literal.

Comment: @RobertHarvey thanks, so I can just remove "0x" from the String to parse ?

Comment: That is correct.

Comment: Have you read the javadoc?

Comment: Yes. It's 950. `int v = 0x03B6;`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Normally, they are interpreted at compile time. You need to use `Integer.decode`.  If you omit the `0x` prefix then you must specify a `radix` and use `parseInt`.

To decode using those strings in realtime, do the following.

```
String[] vals = { "0xF", "#111", "0x17C" };
for (String v : vals) {
    System.out.println(v + " -> " + Integer.decode(v));
}
```

prints

```
0xF -> 15
#111 -> 273
0x17C -> 380
```

Also, note that numbers prefixed with just a `0` will decode as octal.

Comment: thanks, using decode is neater than Integer.parseInt("03B6",16);

Answer (score 5):

The hexadecimal number is just `03B6`.  The hex digits are 0-9 and A-F, which is why you get an exception when you put an 'x' in.

In many languages, you can write a constant in heXadecimal by adding the `0x` prefix.  That tells the compiler that the following digits should be interpreted in base 16 instead of base 10.  `10` is 10, and `0x10` is 16.  Some languages like C also support octal (`010` is 8), and some others support binary (`0b10` is 2).  C is the earliest language I know that uses this 0-prefix idea.

The `parseInt` method, however, parses only the digits, so you have to supply just `03B6`, and use a separate parameter to indicate base 16.